# Win 8.1 FontSize wrong after rotation

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1, uwp-xaml

Why after rotate the app in landscape mode and re-rotate in portrait mode the number of visible items is different ?

As you can see on the attached images, when the app start it shows 25 items and after a double rotation it shows 31 items.

I think is a FontSize issue but i can't understand how to fix it.
This problem is present with devices (10' or 8'display) and with Visual Studio Simulator too.

```
<Page
x:Class="App1.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:App1"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">
<Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ListViewItemTemplate">
        <TextBlock FontSize="24" Text="{Binding}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}"
              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ListViewItemTemplate}">

    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{

    public MainPage()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new MainPageViewModel();
    }


}

public class MainPageViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<string> MyList { get; set; }

    public MainPageViewModel()
    {
        MyList = GetList(); 

    }
    private ObservableCollection<string> GetList()
    {
        var l = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            l.Add("Item " + i);
        }
        return new ObservableCollection<string>(l);
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue in newest OS build 14393. And also cannot reproduce with windows 8.1 phone emulator.

Comment: The problem is the scale Factor. All Windows 8.1 app are scaled to 0.83 factor (100/125) when running on Windows 10 OS. 
This scale factor is not applied immediately on app launch but is applied when the app is rotated for the first time

Comment: I have updated Windows OS to the latest build , but the problem still remaining. I Run it into Visual Studio 2013 Simulator

Comment: @SunteenWu-MSFT : just wanted to mention i reproduced this exact problem in Visual Studio Community 2015, using Microsoft.Windows.Simulator.exe 14.0.23107.0, in a Windows 10 machine, Build 14393, App Target Windows 8.1